# How do I blacklist a hardware item before reboot through the Wubi Win interface?

Tags: installation, networking, wubi, broadcom, blacklist

specifically I need to blacklist b43 broadcom adapter so my installation will stop crashing, but the accessibility button on the windows portion of the setup does not do what it does from a live cd wubi.

[Ubuntuforums Reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1972356)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread would seem to have your answer: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10089820&postcount=8

Comment: nice one, helps alot.  but that is for NOMODESET to deal with a graphics adapter, do I just put b43.blacklist=yes or do I have to put it in a command form?

Comment: Yep, you got it: module_name.blacklist=yes